# Draggable extended with mouseover to show information

Tags: jquery, mouseover

I have set an application of drag and drop using jquery is working fine. A snippet of it is like this `<div class='t1'><span ><img class='draggable' src='tmages/t2.png' id='".$riID."'>" </span></div>.` The problem now is that beside the drag I also require to enable mouse over on it to show the relevant information how is that possible to extend the drag with the mouse over?
I have set the draggable as .

```
$('.t1 span img.draggable').each(function(){
                //alert("drag");
                 //$(this).draggable();
         $('.draggable').draggable({helper: 'clone'});
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to your image code

```
  <img class='draggable' src='tmages/t2.png' id='".$riID."' title="text to display onhover">
```

Comment: if I want my information to be like the alert box how to go about it because I got 3 lines to be shown minimum?